# on the implicit type conversion rules in Solidity

Tags: solidity, type-casting

**Question in one sentence**: Are there seperate implicit type conversion rules for function call resolution (other than the conversion rules for the remaining cases)?

Regarding the array type conversions in Solidity, it seems that the smaller size of types can be implicitly converted into the larger size of types (if the base element types are equal). For example, when we have `uint[2] u2; uint[3] u3;`, `u2` can be assigned into `u3` (`u3:=u2;`), but not vice versa.

My confusing part is that, the situation above does not apply in function call resolutions, i.e., in matching types between argument and formal parameters. Below is an example.

Is it a normal situation ?

```
contract Test{

    uint[2] public u2=[1,2];
    uint[3] public u3;


    function test() public{
        u3=u2;
        test2(u2); // compile error !!
    }

    function test2(uint[3] arr) internal{ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is not!
type conversion is the same, where ever it happens, it follows the same rule(s), function calls, code blocks, or where ever inside the solidity scope.

your example above has a compiler error because its a run time error, and not a logical or syntax error. it will fail when the code runs.

Comment: Why does the code has a run time error? In my example, the statement ``u3=u2;`` can be successfully executed; I checked this in Remix with solc(v 0.7.4).

Comment: its clear. the function `test2` expects three ints, which is 256x3 bits, but it receives only two ints which is 256x2 bits

Comment: Then why does ``u3=u2`` work without runtime or compilation errors? At the function call site ``test2(u2)``, it can be thought that there is an assignment ``arr=u2`` (where ``arr`` is a formal parameter of ``test2``). In other words, I wonder why ``u3=u2`` works but ``arr=u2`` does not work. This is the confusing part to me and why I asked question.

Comment: see this part of documentation which addresses your question [link](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.7.5/types.html?highlight=conversion#explicit-conversions)